# Redmine to DashBoard

Tags: trello, migrate-data

I am using using [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) now, hosted on a server on my local intranet.

I need to move all of the data in Redmine to to Trello now.  Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 3):

There is a [Redmine-Trello Integration tool](https://github.com/cprice-puppet/redmine-trello) one of the puppet-labs guys created for this purpose.

Answer (score 3):

I would've preferred to do this as a comment on Andrew's answer, but anyways..

For people running Redmine 2.x who want to try the Redmine-Trello integration tool, you might want to try [this fork](https://github.com/chaosnhatred/redmine-trello) of the project.